# Inline css is working but when i add the same in external css is not working

Tags: html, css

I have one problem regarding css. i have create a html page and added some padding and margin property in inline css it's working but when i add the same in my external css it's not working

This is my inline coding
`<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-right:-15px; padding:0px;">`

And this is the class in external css

```
.no-margin{margin-right:-15px; padding:0px;}
```

Comment: How do you adding class to your divs? Please write your usage style.

Comment: Check using inspect element, this class might be overwritten with some other styles..

Comment: Add a fiddle or atleast some code so that we can test..

Comment: i add the add in div like this <div class="container-fluid no-margin">

Comment: How are you linking the CSS Sheet? is the path correct?

Comment: yes it is correct, other classes are working well

Comment: container-fluid probably has other styles already for margin and padding that are overriding yours.  Try being more specific with your selector in your external CSS:

div.container-fluid.no-margin {margin-right:-15px; padding:0px;}

also, for what it's worth, a class name of 'no-margin' may not be the best choice if it's margin-right is -15px;  ...it will work, but if someone else has to update/maintain the code, it might be better to call it something else, like 'move-right-15'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
External CSS:

```
.no-margin{margin-right:-15px; padding:0px;}
```

Inline coding:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-margin">
```

Answer (score 0):

this will should work:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-margin">
```

in css:

```
.no-margin{margin-right:-15px; padding:0px;}
```

Comment: if you would like to override inline content you have to add !important to every declaration: 

       .no-margin{margin-right:-15px !important; padding:0px !important;}

Comment: using '!important' here is sort of like using a sledge hammer to hang a picture...you do need a hammer (more specific CSS) but '!important' is likely to cause more trouble.  In a case like this where you have conflicting styles in your CSS, you should try: 1) update or remove the original style if you can (if you don't need it anymore and it's not part of an included library like bootstrap) 2) use a different class name (if the one that's conflicting can't be changed, maybe you shouldn't be using it in this case) or 3) use more specific selectors (multiple classes or an id).

Comment: I know it, it is a basic example. I am only explaining him differents way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

@Mathur never use !important it is very bad practice also do not write inline CSS because later on if you have to change something dynamically you will be having hard times. Also remember that inline css is overwriting your styles.
Always write your code in external file :).

Read more info about !important [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Comment: thanks for reply and nice suggestion. i always use external css but sometime i use internal for testing purpose only. And this time external css not working without !important so any other option to solve this problem

Comment: yes you are able to solve your problem by learning more about CSS Specificity and how it is working by using MDN or there are a lot of free tutorials out there. If i have time I will give you a hand later today.

Comment: Thanks for that but i have faces one another problem right now regarding display of page

Comment: What kind a problem ? Give us more specific info.

Comment: can you share your skype id if possible?

Comment: mladen0f. I am on work right now I will be able to help you in the evening.